# How to scale the y-axis in (tikz, pgfplots) bar plot?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, scaling

I have bar figure that has some large bars than others as shown below:

[image]

My problem is that I can't see the small bars (for example, point 2 or 4). Can we change some parameters to scale the y-axis?

My code is given below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht!]
  \centering
\resizebox{.65\textwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
        xlabel={Number},
        ylabel={Percentage},
        set layers,
        ybar=1.2pt,
        bar width=6pt,
        symbolic x coords={2,4,6,8,10},
        grid=both,
        ymin=0,
        samples=5,
        legend cell align=left,
        ymax=1,
        x label style={font=\footnotesize},
        y label style={font=\footnotesize},
        ticklabel style={font=\footnotesize},
        legend style={at={(0,.82)},anchor=west,font=\scriptsize},
        ]
        %% 
        \addplot[black,fill=red,postaction={pattern=north east lines}] coordinates {
          (2, 0.005) (4, 0.001) (6, 0.2) (8, 0.2) (10, 0.4)
        };
        \addlegendentry{A}
        %% 
        \addplot[black,fill=brown,postaction={pattern=north west lines}] coordinates {
          (2, 0.002) (4, 0.004) (6, 0.2) (8, 0.5) (10, 0.8)
        };
        \addlegendentry{B}
        %% 
        \addplot[black,fill=violet,postaction={pattern=crosshatch}] coordinates {
          (2, 0.2) (4, 0.007) (6, 0.4) (8, 0.7) (10, 0.9)
        };
        \addlegendentry{C}
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
  \caption{The percentage.}
  \label{figure:1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could use a log scale, but lose the ymin=0 first.

Comment: Do you mean just changing the `height` of the axis environment? Then provide an appropriate value to it. The default value is `207pt`.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I did this `ymode=log` but the bars are upside down now.

Comment: Yeah, looking into that.

Comment: @StefanPinnow I would like to see the small bars, I don't know maybe there is some way to enlarge the y-axis.

Comment: As I said: Add for example `height=400pt` to the `axis` option list and see, if that fits your needs. Otherwise try changing the value until it fits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: demo]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht!]
  \centering
\resizebox{.65\textwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{semilogyaxis}[
        xlabel={Number},
        ylabel={Percentage},
        set layers,
        ybar=1.2pt,
        bar width=6pt,
        symbolic x coords={2,4,6,8,10},
        grid=both,
        samples=5,
        legend cell align=left,
        ymax=1,
        x label style={font=\footnotesize},
        y label style={font=\footnotesize},
        ticklabel style={font=\footnotesize},
        legend style={at={(0,.82)},anchor=west,font=\scriptsize},
        log origin y=infty
        ]
        %% 
        \addplot[black,fill=red,postaction={pattern=north east lines}] coordinates {
          (2, 0.005) (4, 0.001) (6, 0.2) (8, 0.2) (10, 0.4)
        };
        \addlegendentry{A}
        %% 
        \addplot[black,fill=brown,postaction={pattern=north west lines}] coordinates {
          (2, 0.002) (4, 0.004) (6, 0.2) (8, 0.5) (10, 0.8)
        };
        \addlegendentry{B}
        %% 
        \addplot[black,fill=violet,postaction={pattern=crosshatch}] coordinates {
          (2, 0.2) (4, 0.007) (6, 0.4) (8, 0.7) (10, 0.9)
        };
        \addlegendentry{C}
      \end{semilogyaxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
  \caption{The percentage.}
  \label{figure:1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```